# How to pass parameters while rendering to another page in angular?

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to pass few variables to the rendering page. How can I do that in angular? Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get in different ways.

1. You can store the data in localsotrage at render time and you can get that data from localsotarge.

use it before render : `localStorage.setItem("key", value);`

use it after render : `localStorage.getItem("key");`

**OR**
2. You can pass the data in your URL as a parameter and get that data after your page render.

EX: `/url/:parameters`

get the parameters `$routeParams.parameters`

To use `$routeParams`, first you need to inject in your controller

Answer (score 0):

`/someurl/:param` is the better approach because when the page redirects from some other website or directly open that URL in private window. It'll throw an error because there is no data in local storage.

**Ng Router**

```
function($routeParams){
  $scope.param=$routeParams.param;
});
```

**ui-router**

```
function ($stateParams) {
  console.log($stateParams);
}
```